# Replacement for deprecated event handling in Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-events, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

I have a hyper-critical Facebook app (for our organization) that used Graph API v1.0 to read and post events for our [closed] Facebook group. Now that Graph v1.0 is deprecated and event support is "no longer supported" for Graph v2.0 it has literally killed our ability to use this app - or Facebook itself for our social media needs.

Are there any other or "replacement" APIs that would allow my app to post events - even if it is just into one, single, controlled group?

Comment: Creating events was removed in API v2.0

Comment: I know. Hence, the question about any kind of replacement for it's functionality.

Comment: If there was a replacement the changelog wouldn't say it been removed.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a great solution, but the 1.0 API will be available through April 2015.  You could downgrade to the old API until then - certainly not a good long term plan, but it could give you time to find another option